# 4 Primes in 9 consecutive Integers

Tags: prime-numbers

This is not so much a question, as it is an interesting (to me at least) observation.

Part of a more complex problem involved finding primes in 9 consecutive Integers greater than 2.

Not being the smartest math guy out "there", I used my current math knowledge + logic, and quickly removed all even numbers as well as numbers ending in 5.

Left were numbers ending in 1, 3, 7 & 9.

I scribbled down some code in Python, and noticed that every time I found 4 primes in 9 consecutive integers, the lowest one always ended in 1.

I concentrated on numbers divisible by 3 and found that the **lowest prime MOD 3 had to equal 2**:

[image: Finding 4 Primes in 9 consecutive Integers]

Remembering that if the sum of digits is divisible by 3, then the number itself is too, I logically discovered that the sum MOD 3 would increase by 2 when going from a number ending in 9 to one ending in 1, hence any sequence of "prime candidates" starting with a number ending in anything by 1 would contain all 3 possible results of the number MOD 3 = [0,1,2], whereas only a sequence starting with a number ending in 1, would only contain 2 of those, and therefore be able to have a sequence with all 4 numbers being prime candidates.

This may be extremely elementary for most of you math experts out there, but I just found it interesting, and discoveries like these are why I love math.

I would love to hear more facts about this particular "primes in 9 consecutive integers" study.

Thanks.

Comment: You're basically looking for two consecutive pairs of twin primes. This is the only way for $9$ consecutive integers to contain $4$ primes. So I suggest that you simply Google *consecutive pairs of twin primes*.

Comment: I know this could probably be found from the Google search you suggested (I looked briefly), but is it correct that the smallest of the $4$ consecutive primes has a $1$ in the units place?  I can see that $5, 7, 11, 13$ work, but anything larger?

Comment: Good catch! - Missed that one, which only works because 5 is a prime.
However, I believe the above proves that any numbers above have to start with a prime ending in 1.

Comment: @CSCFCEM, it's not just consecutive primes, as those can start with any of the "endings" [1,3,7,9], but consecutive primes in 9 consecutive integers.

Comment: @OleDrewsJensen, Yea reading what I wrote I see I did not mention the 9 consecutive integer part (but I was thinking it!! I promise!).

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard to show that any 'quadruplet primes' of the type described in the post are congruent (smallest to largest) to $11, 13, 17, 19$ $\pmod{30}$, with the exception of some quadruplets where the smallest prime is less than or equal to $5$.

If this sort of thing is interesting, one can think about double quadruplet primes where the smallest primes in each quadruplet differ by $30$.  The smallest such grouping (I think) is $1006301, 1006303, 1006307, 1006309, 1006331, 1006333, 1006337, 1006339$.

Comment: Thanks, and you are absolutely correct:

>>> lastp=11

>>> for p in range(11,100000000000,10):

...   if kingole.isprime(p):

...     if kingole.isprime(p+2):

...       if kingole.isprime(p+6):

...         if kingole.isprime(p+8):

...           if p-lastp==30:

...             print(lastp,p)

...           lastp=p

...

1006301 1006331

Comment: _(sorry, unable to format a comment)_

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for $2$ consecutive pairs of twin primes, which is the only way for $9$ consecutive integers to contain $4$ primes larger than $3$.

It is not known whether there are infinitely many pairs of twin primes, so it is obviously not known whether there are infinitely many **consecutive** pairs of twin primes.

Of course, except for the first set ($5,7,11,13$), every such set will contain exactly one number ending with each digit ($1,3,7,9$).

There is nothing "too special" about it, as the only reason for this is the use of the decimal base system for representation.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Again, this may not be "anything too special" for a lot of you guys, but I found it pretty interesting. I didn't pay too much attention to a lot of math back in the stoneage when I went to school, so the majority of my math knowledge now is from self-study, experimentation, and trial-and-error.

Comment: @OleDrewsJensen: You're welcome.